# Predicted Rank Values from Dict

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Lets say I have a time dict

```
dict = {
'9': {'auth': '9', 'duration': 154.92},
'10': {'auth': '10', 'duration': 132.72},
'4': {'auth': '4', 'duration': 144.59}
}
```

and how can I get the "rank" value from the dict with a new duration number, lets say 133.92.

It should return dict index 1, since the top list is:
    auth-10|duration:132.72
    auth-4|duration:144.59
    auth-9|duration:154.92

and 133.92 is bigger than 132.72, but less than 144.59 or 154.92

I'm sorry if Its unclear explained, but I tried my best.

EDIT:

I'm trying it again:
I need a function which returns the "predicted/rank" for a custom duration from the sorted list/sorted by "duration/DESC".
So a duration of 160 would return the last place, which is 4. (index+1). A 120 duration should return me the first position which is index 0 or 1st (index+1).

Comment: Dictionaries have no order, so there is no 'index'.

Comment: What entry would you return if the new duration number is 130.10?

Comment: a 0, since its the first "sorted" item. (By duration, INT, desc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MartijnPieters mentioned, dictionaries lack indices, but they do have keys. The following function `pred()` (short for "predecessor") returns the key of the item whose duration is the largest duration <= the passed duration. It returns `None` (which can be tested for) if the passed duration is smaller than all of the durations in the dictionary:

```
from bisect import bisect_left

def pred(duration, entries):
    entries = list(entries.items())
    entries.sort(key = lambda x: x[1]['duration'])
    durations = [x[1]['duration'] for x in entries]
    j = bisect_left(durations,duration)
    if j == 0:
        return None
    else:
        return entries[j-1][0]
```

For example, if

```
d = {
'9': {'auth': '9', 'duration': 154.92},
'10': {'auth': '10', 'duration': 132.72},
'4': {'auth': '4', 'duration': 144.59}
}
```

(by the way -- don't use `dict` as an identifier since it has a predefined meaning in Python) then:

```
>>> pred(133.92,d)
'10'
>>> pred(149.92,d)
'4'
>>> pred(159.92,d)
'9'
>>> pred(129.92,d)
>>>
```

Note that

```
>>> pred(129.92,d) == None
True
```

**On Edit**: Here is another variation on the same idea, one that returns an integer rank:

```
def rank(duration, entries):
    entries = list(entries.items())
    durations = sorted(x[1]['duration'] for x in entries)
    return bisect_left(durations,duration)
```

Then:

```
>>> rank(133.92,d)
1
>>> rank(129.92,d)
0
```

**Final Edit**: At the cost of some readability, here is a 1-liner:

```
def rank(duration, entries):
    return bisect_left(sorted(v['duration'] for v in entries.values()),duration)
```

Comment: That sounds interesting, but It doesnt return what I actually want to get.
Currently it returns the account_id, but I kinda need to predict the "duration" rank from the dict. Only by the "d = {..." dict, I have currently only 3 ranks if they are sorted by duration. Now When I compare a new duration, it should return which "position/rank" it would return in the sorted duration dict.

Comment: @Fragkiller The second function that I just added seems a little more like what you are looking for, though both might be useful.

Comment: Awesome, your edit is perfectly what I was looking for. Never heard of that function bisect_left, thanks.

Comment: Can I just ask, when does it return "None", since I see that above?

Comment: @Fragkiller The last edit should be even more efficient

Comment: It no longer returns `None`. It always returns an int.